# More the one instance of tor with c#

Tags: c#, tor

I am trying to open more then one instance of tor browser with different identities with c#.

One of the brwoswers opens fine:

[image]

But when the code opens the second I get empty browser:

[image]

Here is my c# code:

```
IWebDriver browser;

FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1");
profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks_port", 9150);
browser =  new FirefoxDriver(profile);
//    browser.Quit();

//Firefox's proxy driver executable is in a folder already
//  on the host system's PATH environment variable.
browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://dnsleaktest.com");
//IWebElement header = browser.FindElement(By.Id(“site - header"));

//Assert.True(header.Displayed);
// browser.Close();

Thread.Sleep(10000);
IWebDriver browser2;

FirefoxProfile profile2 = new FirefoxProfile();
profile2.SetPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
profile2.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1");
profile2.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks_port", 9152);
browser2 = new FirefoxDriver(profile2);
//    browser.Quit();

//Firefox's proxy driver executable is in a folder already
//  on the host system's PATH environment variable.
browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://dnsleaktest.com");
//IWebElement header = browser.FindElement(By.Id(“site - header"));

//Assert.True(header.Displayed);
// browser.Close();
```

Please correct my English if needed

## NuGet:

- NUnit3TestAdapter
- List itSelenium.WebDriverem

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
        //Firefox's proxy driver executable is in a folder already
        //  on the host system's PATH environment variable.
        browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://dnsleaktest.com");
        //IWebElement header = browser.FindElement(By.Id(“site - header"));
```

To this:

```
        //Firefox's proxy driver executable is in a folder already
        //  on the host system's PATH environment variable.
        browser2.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://dnsleaktest.com");
        //IWebElement header = browser.FindElement(By.Id(“site - header"));
```

You were navigating the first browser object when you needed to be navigating the second browser object.

Comment: Now the second browser says: "The proxy server is refusing connections"

Comment: @BadAss Do you have a second tor instance running and listening on port 9152?

Comment: Even if I put some other port number it still the same problem

Comment: @BadAss Open your task manager and see how many **tor instances** are running. You need at least 2

Comment: @Eser But how to fix?

Comment: @BadAss see the *"expert bundle"* at https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en. Tor core without a browser (Since you create your own browsers you don't need it). (Or simply use the same socks port for both browser instances. (That would mean using a single tor instance) )

Comment: @Eser But I need differet ip addresses

Comment: @BadAss So you know the solution. "expert bundle"

Comment: @Eser I can't find "expert bundle" in link that you gave

Comment: @BadAss Come on, open "Microsodt Windows" tab... I quit... Seems like you won't be able to use it. Good Luck.